# Change Links to Colored Background and White Font

Tags: hyperref, color, boxes, links

Is it possible to create hyperlinks with a color background and a white font? I have been trying with package `hyperref` and `hypersetup`, but have not found this option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example, with a light purple background:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{lightpurple}{RGB}{182,149,192}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,urlcolor={white}}

\let\hrefori\href
\renewcommand{\href}[2]{{\setlength{\fboxsep}{1pt}\colorbox{lightpurple}{\hrefori{#1}{#2}}}}

\begin{document}

This is a \href{http://www.example.com}{link}.

\end{document}
```

---

**EDIT.**   Here is another solution using the `soul` package.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{lightpurple}{RGB}{182,149,192}

\usepackage{soul}
\sethlcolor{lightpurple}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,urlcolor={white}}

\let\hrefori\href
\renewcommand{\href}[2]{\hrefori{#1}{\hl{#2}}}

\begin{document}

This is a \href{http://www.example.com}{link}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Very cool! But how come when I change `red` it's not changing the background color?

Comment: Rather, I see it is now. But I'm trying to change it to light purple, and bold the font. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Replace `#2` with `\textbf{#2}` in the definition of `\href`; i.e.,  `\renewcommand{\href}[2]{{\setlength{\fboxsep}{1pt}\colorbox{lightpurple}{\hrefori{#1}{\textbf{#2}}}}}` to get the text in boldface.

Comment: Ok, so this is all perfect. The only problem is that now the links are running over, and not breaking at the end of the line

Comment: The second solution takes care of the line breaking. Thanks!